# How to detect NFC tag was removed

Tags: android, tags, nfc, mifare, detach

I am new at NFC technology. I am trying to read and write Mifare Classic 4K tags. I succeeded reading and writing. I can detect the tag on `onNewIntent` action.

My problem is that I could't detect when an NFC tag was removed (similar to `onNewIntent` when detecting a tag).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Catch  `IO_EXCEPTION`

Comment: I want to inform me immediately it when it is removed.Instead of at reading and writing process

Comment: Catch `IO` an display `Dailog` with error. what's wrong with that?

Comment: I mean should I catch I/O exception at which operation except reading and writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check by calling
isoDep.isConnected();
in IsoDep

Comment: I wonder how you would do that for a MIFARE 4K tag. They do not expose an IsoDep interface. Also note thaz calling isConnected is not quite that reliable as one might expect it to be.

Comment: I am using card reader mode, not trigger by android intent.

Answer (score 9):

There is no event that notifies your app if a tag is removed from the reader. A typical approach to detect removal is to actively poll the tag (e.g. by reading an NDEF message or a data block) until you receive IOException indicating that communication with the tag was lost.

---

#### UPDATE

As of Android API level 24 this is no longer true. There is now a method

```
NfcAdapter.ignore(tag, debounceMs, tagRemovedListener, handler);
```

that can be used to register a callback for getting notifications upon tag removal. This method may have some issue though, so carefully read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#ignore(android.nfc.Tag,%20int,%20android.nfc.NfcAdapter.OnTagRemovedListener,%20android.os.Handler)) on side-effects/corner cases.

Comment: Is it not supported by the nfc system service in android itself? or it's just that android doesn't provide an API for that?

Comment: @Yashasvi The NFC stack certainly knows when a tag disappeared from the field and does some internal clean up, but there is no notification mechanism to the application layer.

Comment: @Michael Roland please can you provide example about how we can use NFCAdapter.ignore ?